# Disable COM-Addin through code

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, excel-interop

Within our company we have 2 addins who don't get along within Excel. One of the addins is from SAP (e.g. no possibility to modify). The other one is a local one developped using [Add In Express](https://www.add-in-express.com/)

The problem limits itself to Excel. When we try to lift a document from protected view. using the following code

```
ExcelApp.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit()
```

When we execute that line of code, then the other (SAP) plugin starts throwing access violations.

```
1st error: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt
2nd error: Exception from HResult 0x800A03EC
```

Right now i'm trying to fix the conflict. But i'm stuck.
I can't find another way to succesfully lift a document out of protected view

Temporally disabling the SAP addIn doesn't seem to work aswell. Because [Application.Addins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-addins-property-excel) doesn't contain the COM-Addins. And [Application.CommAddins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-comaddins-property-excel) throws the following error:

```
       ExcelApp.COMAddIns   The embedded interop type 'COMAddIns' does not contain a 
       definition for'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application' since it was not used 
       in the compiled assembly. Consider casting to object or changing the 'Embed Interop Types' 
       property to true.
```

Yet `Embed Interop Types` is set to true.

So anyone any Ideas?

**Note**
Disabling `Protected view` is not an option. As it was decided on coporate-level :-(

Comment: The Object model should work if you use the progid of the com addin - and you then should be able to set the Connect property to False to disconnect it.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams any idea why he would be complaining about the embed Interop types then?

Comment: It may be a bug in Interop - try doing it from VBA - the VBA object model seems to work OK. Note that if the COM addin is installed for all users (which it probably is)  I am not sure you can disconnect it using automation because disconnecting requires Admin privileges.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams thanks for your input. Its worth a shot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the issue. With thanks to [Charles Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88173/charles-williams)
Using the following bit of code I can disable/enable certain COM-Addins using vb.code

The `SapExcelAddIn` in this case, is the AddIn which causes all our problems.

```
For Each certAddin As Object In ExcelApp.COMAddIns
      log("progId:" & certAddin.progId) 'Logging the id of all Com-addins
      If (certAddin.progId.Equals("SapExcelAddIn")) Then
           log("disconnecting:" & certAddin.progId)
           certAddin.Connect = False
      End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone wants to do this in C#, here is some code to disable multiple COM-AddIns, specified by name via an array argument:

```cs
private void TryDisableCommAddIns(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app, string[] addInsToDisable)
        {
            if(addInsToDisable == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            COMAddIns comAddIns = app.COMAddIns;
            foreach (string addInName in addInsToDisable)
            {
                //If you have a logger you could log a debug statement such as: $"Disabling COM AddIn: {addInName}"
                COMAddIn commAddInOrNull = GetCommAddInOrNull(comAddIns, addInName);
                if(commAddInOrNull != null)
                {
                    commAddInOrNull.Connect = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private COMAddIn GetCommAddInOrNull(COMAddIns comAddIns, string addInName)
        {
            try
            {
                return comAddIns.Item(addInName);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //If you have a logger you could log a debug statement such as: $"No COM AddIn found with name: {addInName}"
                return null;
            }
        }
```